# Fleshing out specific equation in "Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R"

Tags: self-study, expectation-maximization

Page 157 of "Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R" reads:

> A specific solution (Geyer and Thompson, 1992) consists in using only
>   the conditional distribution $k(\pmb{ z }|\pmb{x},\hat{\theta}_{(0)})$
>   due to the identity:
>
> $$\arg\max_{\theta}L(\theta|\pmb x) =
>  \arg\max_{\theta}\log\frac{g(\pmb x|\theta)}{g(\pmb x|\theta_{(0)})} =
>  \arg\max_{\theta}\log\mathbb{E}_{\theta_{(0)}}\left[\frac{f(\pmb x,
>  \pmb z|\theta)}{f(\pmb x,\pmb z|\theta_{(0)})}|\pmb{x}\right]$$

I'm not sure I understand the last equality and was wondering if anyone here had already fleshed it and could maybe share the steps.

Comment: can you post any attempts you've  made at getting from the RHS to the middle term?

Comment: That's the problem: I don't know how to write the rightmost term in a way that it would related to the middle one. I don't see any related fleshed out expression earlier in the book (it resembles the ones for $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[Z_i|\pmb x]$ on p 155 but that one isn't fleshed out either, though at least it is intuitive to me)

Comment: This looks like the fundamental identity of EM algorithm. Take a look at this writeup. I think there's a lot to unpack in the above equalities. http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes8.pdf

Comment: Essentially, if you're simulating a bunch of "hidden" variables (z) under the current parameter estimate ($\theta_0$) you can marginalze them out conditional on the observed data (RHS) and then you're left with a function of just the "free parameter" $\theta$ and the data (hence a regular likelihood) (This is the basis for the E-step). EM uses the variables (z) to make the model tractable, and this identity shows that the expected value of $\theta$ after the M step is, in fact, the optimizer of the original likelihood.